# XSL - What is the namespace for? and what does it?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I know the functionality of Namespaces which is used in C++ and C.
But I do not understand this line of code in XSLT:

```
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
```

What is it there for? What would happen if I miss this?
(Nothing happens if I delete this line)...
And what is this pointing to?`

I've read some Posts about this in W3Cschools... But I still didn't
understood ...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp. There are a million tutorials on namespaces from a google search.

Comment: and why I need a Namespace in XSLT then? I just got one XSLT... there can be no conflict between XML and XSLT I guess.

Comment: @H.Senkaya: Unless your XSLT generates XML...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question deserves a better explanation.

**Here is an element named** `table`:

```
<table material="wood"
       legs="4" shape="rectangle" type="dining"/>
```

From the values of its 4 attributes it is clear that this describes a *wooden*, *dining table* with *four legs*, and *rectangular* shape.

**Here is another** `table` **element**:

```
<table name="Product">
  <columns>
    <column name="id"/>
    <column name="name" type="string"/>
    <column name="price" type="decimal"/>
    <column name="date-produced" type="date"/>
  </columns>
  <rows>
   <row id="1" name="bike" price="300" quantity="2"
               date-produced="2013-08-12"/>
  </rows>
</table>
```

**This clearly isn’t a piece of furniture**, but is probably a *relational database table*.

We see that the two “table” elements have different meaning and nothing in common – they happen to have the same name, but they belong to different *vocabularies*.

**Here are some more examples of element names that can belong to different vocabularies**:

```
 <furniture:table/>
 <sql:table/>
 <resataurant:table/>
 <html:table/>
```

---

```
 <sql:column/>
 <architecture:column/>
 <table:column>
```

---

```
 <css:style/>
 <architecture:style/>
 <fashion:style/>
```

Here we have three different element names: “table”, “column” and “style”, each belonging to > 1 vocabularies.

There are 8 different vocabularies represented by these elements:

1. `furniture`, `sql`, `restaurant` and `html` for the name **`table`**
2. `sql`, `architecture` and `table` for the name **`column`**
3. `css`, `architecture` and `fashion` for the name **`style`**.

**The purpose of a namespace** is to identify a vocabulary to which a given name belongs. In other words, *to disambiguate two identical names that belong to different vocabularies*.

**Here is a typical** *namespace declaration*:

> <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
>   `xmlns:xsl`=`"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"`>

It associates a *namespace prefix* to a *namespace URI* (Uniform Resource Identifier).

The effect of this namespace declaration is that the name: `xsl:stylesheet` belongs to the namespace with namespace-uri the string `“http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform”`

Different namespace prefixes can be associated to the same namespace-uri -- even within the same XML document.

However, **a namespace URI must be globally unique**: the XSLT namespace is always the same string, regardless of what prefix is associated with it.

**The prefix** :

- Is the part of the attribute name that follows the `"xmlns:"`
- Cannot contain the character `":"`
- If the attribute name is only `xmlns` then the prefix is "" (the empty string)

**The NS URI**:

- Can be any string: `"^%$23rt"`, `"http://myComp.com"`, `"my:my"`
- **Must be unique**.
- **Could** be meaningful URL.
- If meaningful URL, this doesn’t require a page with that URL to exist. The XML processor doesn’t issue any HTTP request to access this URL.

**Do note**:

- **The namespace URI must be unique**: this is the most important requirement for a namespace.
- *Could* (but isn’t necessary to) be a meaningful URL – what is more important is the uniqueness of the string.
- *If* the NS URI is a meaningful URL, this doesn’t require that a page with this URL should exist. **No HTTP request is issued for the NS URI**.

[image: Common misconceptions]

---

**Now, to answer the specific questions:**

> I do not understand this line of code in XSLT:
>   `xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"`
>
> What is it there for?

This is the namespace declaration for the **XSLT namespace** that defines the **XSLT vocabulary**

**Its purpose is to disambiguate** any element and attribute names that are in this namespace from any other occurences of the same names, that belong to other vocabularies (or do not belong to any vocabulary (belong to the "empty" vocabulary).

> What would happen if I miss this?

In case there is no XSLT namespace declaration specified in an XML document, then:

- An XSLT processor will not discover any `<xsl:stylesheet>` declarations, instructions, elements or attributes that it understands. It will not do any work and will likely report errors.
- In case that there is no namespace declaration with a prefix "xsl", but inside the document there are element (or attribute) names with this prefix, then even the XML parser will raise an error that the input is not a well-formed XML document.

> And what is this pointing to?

As explained earlier, the namespace-uri can be any string and may not necessarily be a syntactically valid URL. In case when it *is* a syntactically valid URL, there is no obligation that there would be an HTTP server that would provide HTTP response for any HTTP request with this URL.

And the XSLT processor definitely doesn't issue any such HTTP request -- anyone can prove this by disconnecting from all networks and performing any XSLT transformation -- the transformation still produces its results.

But in this specific case, if you try this URL in your browser, you will see that the W3C has been friendly to its numerous users and a page is actually served:

[image: The W3C "XSLT-Namespace" page]

> I've read some Posts about this in W3Cschools... But I still didn't
>   understood ...

W3Schools is not considered to be a good resource about XML/XSLT/XPath -- as explained at: [**W3Fools**](http://www.w3fools.com/)

The only authoritative source about XML, XML Namespaces and XSLT is their corresponding specification: [**http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/), [**http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-names-20060816/**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml-names-20060816/), and [**https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116)  (the latter is the XSLT 1.0 spec -- separate specifications exist for XSLT 2.0 and for XSLT 3.0)

However, the W3C specifications were not written with the purpose to be user-friendly. If anyone wants to learn more about XSLT and XML, I would recommend my video course at Pluralsight: [**XSLT 2.0 and 1.0 Foundations**](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/xslt-foundations-part1)  -- the second module of this course explains in details the concept of XML namespaces.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Never read a better explanatation! After that post of you I understood the real purpose behind Namespace!

Answer (score 2):

> Nothing happens if I delete this line

Well, that's just not true. If you remove the namespace declaration, your stylesheet will stop working. In fact, it will not be an XSLT stylesheet anymore.

The XSLT processor uses the namespace to distinguish between XSLT instructions (which the processor must execute) and other elements, such as literal result elements (which will be copied to the output tree).